# getting ADBannerView error message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating `ADBannerView` in my iPhone application programmatically,

can anybody say me that,

why I am geeting this message in my console,

> `ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0xb5328d0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
in .h file 
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface YOUR_FILE : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>{

 ADBannerView *adView;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;

@end;
```

in .m file

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad  {

...
...
...
...
     adView.delegate =self;
    }

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    NSLog(@"iAdBanner failed");


}
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{

    NSLog(@"iAdBanner loaded");



}
```

Comment: thanks manish modi, its resolved, after doing that one, now i am getting another message in my console i.e., ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x7c85e10) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view. can u plz give me a solution for this too